# Cannot start rake on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ruby

I am following instructions to set up `napa` from [here](https://github.com/bellycard/napa/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md).

I have been able to successfully install `ruby`, `gem` and `bundle`.

In one of the steps I have to use `rake` like `rake db:reset`. But running it I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I solve this issue?